# Using mobile switch inside kendoWindow

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile, kendo-window

Trying to use kendo-mobile-switch inside kendowWindow. The switch is displayed fine, but doesn't toggle. On the same page with the same included kendo css/js the same mobile switch toggles just fine if used on the page itself, not inside the kendoWindow.

I've looked in the page source and it looks like when switch **does toggle**, the following transformation is added:

```
<span class="km-switch-handle" style="transform: translateX(27px) translateY(0px);">
```

The same switch in the "non-toggled" state looks like this:

```
<span class="km-switch-handle" style="transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px);">
```

However, if I look at the source of the toggle inside kendoWindow, in both toggled and non-toggled states it looks like this:

```
<span class="km-switch-handle" style="transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px);">
```

I've also dogged through kendo.all.js and it looks like when switch is toggled, it computes the offset it needs to transform itself based on the position. My guess is when displayed in the kendoWindow, get position logic fails/doesn't work properly:

```
_position: function (position) {
                var that = this;
                that.position = position;
                that.handle.css(TRANSFORMSTYLE, 'translatex(' + position + 'px)');
                if (that._animateBackground) {
                    that.background.css(MARGINLEFT, that.origin + position);
                }
            },
```

Any idea what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

Guess I'm going to answer my own question:
Found a very similar issue when mobile switch is used inside the list view:
http://www.telerik.com/forums/angular-kendo-mobile-switch-in-list-view-template

The switch in this example behaves exactly the same as it does in kendoWindow. Judging by the title of the issue, the problem was with "angular compilation is performed before the items are inserted into the DOM". This would explain why position is not calculated in the case with kendoWindow.